# Prevent autoscroll when keyboard appear Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, forms

I've developed a survey form. When user enter name his name appear on top in mobile view. To enhance more user experience. I'm stuck in one issue which is, I can't turn off auto scroll when keyboard appear.

```
<input (click)="onFocusInput()" placeholder="" class="form-control" formControlName="name" required>

onFocusInput() {
//Method 1
window.scroll({
  top: 100,
  behavior: "smooth" // You can use "auto" instead of "smooth" for instant scrolling
});
//Method 2
// this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor("id1");

//Method 3
// const targetElement = document.getElementById("id1");
// if (targetElement) {
//   targetElement.scrollIntoView({
//     behavior: "smooth",
//     block: "start",
//     inline: "nearest"
//   });
// }
}
```

I want to set scroll according to my need. I don't want keyboard to autoscroll. Your suggestion will be appreciable.

https://lapwetypeform.netlify.app/

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the **[VirtualKeyboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VirtualKeyboard_API)** that appears on mobile devices. In the docs of it, there is also an example provided to overlay the keyboard instead of adjusting the viewport height:

```js
// Check for support of the VirtualKeyboard API
if ("virtualKeyboard" in navigator) {
  navigator.virtualKeyboard.overlaysContent = true;

  navigator.virtualKeyboard.addEventListener("geometrychange", (event) => {
    const { x, y, width, height } = event.target.boundingRect;
  });
}
```

But it is marked as experimental and support for Firefox or Safari isn't there yet...
For more examples you can also visit the chrome developer site for this ([Full control with the VirtualKeyboard API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/virtual-keyboard/)).

Comment: Is it for angular? I paste given code in typescript it says, `navigator.virtualKeyboard' is of type 'unknown'.ts(18046)`

Comment: @Python_bot_here As said, it is experimental so `virtualKeyboard` is not a known property of the global `navigator` type definition. Either you write your own type definition for it or just parse it as type `any`.